# Method to populate a List<string> with class constant values. C#

Tags: c#, reflection, constants

I'm in need to create a method which allows me to populate a `List<string>` with the values of the constants that are defined in the own class.

To give you a quick example of the numerous (`20` in total) `const`ants that are defined in the class:

```
private const string NAME1 = "NAME1";
private const string NAME2 = "NAME2";
private const string NAME3 = "NAME3";
...
```

As you can see, the name of the constant equals the value of it, if that can help.

So far, looking at examples of different types of solutions that I've found in StackOverflow about similar problems, I've come up with this:

```
public static List<string> GetConstantNames()
{
   List<string> names = new List<string>();
   Type type = typeof(ClassName);

   foreach (PropertyInfo property in type.GetType().GetProperties())
   {
      names.Add(property.Name);
   }

   return names;
}
```

My experience as a programmer is quite low, same as my experience with C#;
I'm not sure if `type.GetType().GetProperties()` references the constant names, 
same happens with the `property.Name` line.

Does this method do what I'm asking?

Comment: Please no, if you want to do that, you are implementing something in a wrong way for sure. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno Hi, what I'm trying to achieve is to create a method that allows me to create a List with the values of the constants of the class.
In the example that I posted the idea would be to, on calling the method `GetConstantNames()`, get a List that contains the values of the constants that are defined on top, something like `List<string> names = "NAME1","NAME2","NAME3",...`

Comment: yes but why? It isn't a good practice

Comment: Do you have an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Your reads as if you are asking about your solution rather than explaining your underlying question.

Comment: Having a group of string variables with name equal value is often better as an array (or a list) of strings. Another possibility is to have an `enum` type and use the ".ToString()` method to get the names as strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to get `const`s you should operate with *fields*, not *properties*:

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;

  ...

  public static List<string> GetConstantNames() {
    return typeof(ClassName)
      .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
      .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly) // constants, not readonly
      .Where(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(string)) // of type string
      .Select(fi => fi.Name) 
      .ToList();
  }
```

If you want to get *both* `const` names and values:

```
  public static Dictionary<string, string> GetConstantNamesAndValues() {
    return typeof(ClassName)
      .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static)
      .Where(fi => fi.IsLiteral && !fi.IsInitOnly) // constants, not readonly
      .Where(fi => fi.FieldType == typeof(string)) // of type string
      .ToDictionary(fi => fi.Name, fi => fi.GetValue(null) as String); 
  }
```